# Vim display won't refresh

Tags: vimrc

I am using Vim, and somehow the Vim doesn't refresh display properly. 
[image]

For example, I use `set cursorline` and move to the next time, the remnant of the cursorline remains. Same goes to when I type`:`, the bottom panel is supposed to be cleared, but the text remained there, which is really annoying. I also tried `vim -U NONE -u NONE -N` but it didn't solve the problem either. My system is xterm and vim is able to detect the right xterm. I am at a loss as to how to fixed the problem.

I did find a temporary solution, that is type `:!clear` in Vim, which will keep Vim functional for the session, but it's annoying that I have do this every time I go to vim. Just wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution. Basically it's an encoding issue. For some reason my Vim doesn't work with UTF-8, so I set my system LANG to ASCII, now everything works just fine. In case anyone runs into similar problem, tinker your encoder setting, which might help.

Comment: What was your `LANG` set to before? What's the output of `:echo has('multi_byte')` in Vim? Also, what is the value of `:verbose set encoding` with the two different LANG settings?